# Adobe Illustrator Snapping Lines and Rectangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using AI CS6 to make a floor plan type of illustration and want everything to snap to pixel.

These are my settings:

- Snap to Point ON
- Smart Guides ON
- Align New Objects to Pixel Grid ON
- All objects: Align to Pixel Grid ON
- Align Strokes: Middle (first box)

However, some rectangles are forced aligned at 0.5 pixel grid, some are 1 pixel grid, and no matter what I do, they won't line up with each other.

E.g., one rectangle at x:10 y:10 width:10 height:10; another at x:10.5 y:10.5 width:10 height:10

Force typing in 10 for the second rectangle won't work, align buttons won't work, aligning them all to the center won't work either. They'd always 0.5 pixels from lining up.

Also, there are rectangles with identical widths but they look 1 pixel off on the canvas. Again, they all have the same border styles.

Any insight on the mechanics behind all these would help. I'm hoping to not only fix this but also understand how this all work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the dialogue box or dropbox you are force aligning them it has a square with 9 points and one of points will be of different colour. If the center point is of different color means it is selected and all the position coordinates you are seeing for that object are of that object's center's coordinates. If you change it to top-left point in that small square you will be able to snap topleft corner of your object maybe this is what you want.

More help [1](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html) [2](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html) [3](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/rulers-grids-guides-crop-marks.html#use_the_grid)